# Как починить Линукс? Failed to write entry (), ignoring: Read-only file system

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Ubuntu 18.04 lts + kde plasma (но не kubuntu)

Проц amd ryzen 3 2200

Периодически самопроизвольно тухнет система, закрываются все приложения, гаснет экран и на нем выводится 2 символа: ^@

В чем может быть проблема и как ее решить?

Upd. Бывает так, что оболочка не тухнет, но в консоли при этом на любую команду ответ not found (pwd работает)
Если открыть консоль через ctrl+alt+f*, то будет такая балда:

Failed to write entry (), ignoring: Read-only file system

Upd:

Я допер, что можно посмотреть логи через journalctl и увидел, что в последние 10 секунд жизни сессии работы gui в лог писались такие вещи:

```
    ноя 14 10:18:14 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: exception Emask 0x11 SAct 0x7800000f SErr 0x400000 action 0x6 frozen
ноя 14 10:18:14 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: irq_stat 0x48000008, interface fatal error
ноя 14 10:18:14 ruslan kernel: ata1: SError: { Handshk }
ноя 14 10:18:14 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
ноя 14 10:18:14 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: cmd 61/18:00:10:27:14/00:00:17:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq dma 12288 out
                                           res 40/00:18:a0:59:54/00:00:2d:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
ноя 14 10:18:14 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ноя 14 10:18:14 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
ноя 14 10:18:14 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: cmd 61/18:08:e8:58:54/00:00:2d:00:00/40 tag 1 ncq dma 12288 out
                                           res 40/00:18:a0:59:54/00:00:2d:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
ноя 14 10:18:14 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ноя 14 10:18:14 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
ноя 14 10:18:14 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: cmd 61/18:10:60:59:54/00:00:2d:00:00/40 tag 2 ncq dma 12288 out
                                           res 40/00:18:a0:59:54/00:00:2d:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
ноя 14 10:18:14 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ноя 14 10:18:14 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
ноя 14 10:18:14 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: cmd 61/18:18:a0:59:54/00:00:2d:00:00/40 tag 3 ncq dma 12288 out
                                           res 40/00:18:a0:59:54/00:00:2d:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
ноя 14 10:18:14 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ноя 14 10:18:14 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
ноя 14 10:18:15 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: cmd 61/70:d8:e8:29:7a/06:00:2d:00:00/40 tag 27 ncq dma 843776 out
                                           res 40/00:18:a0:59:54/00:00:2d:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
ноя 14 10:18:15 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ноя 14 10:18:15 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
ноя 14 10:18:15 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: cmd 61/90:e0:60:dd:79/02:00:2d:00:00/40 tag 28 ncq dma 335872 out
                                           res 40/00:18:a0:59:54/00:00:2d:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
ноя 14 10:18:15 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ноя 14 10:18:15 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
ноя 14 10:18:15 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: cmd 61/a8:e8:58:30:7a/03:00:2d:00:00/40 tag 29 ncq dma 479232 out
                                           res 40/00:18:a0:59:54/00:00:2d:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
ноя 14 10:18:15 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ноя 14 10:18:15 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
ноя 14 10:18:15 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: cmd 61/08:f0:b0:9d:9a/00:00:31:00:00/40 tag 30 ncq dma 4096 out
                                           res 40/00:18:a0:59:54/00:00:2d:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
ноя 14 10:18:15 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ноя 14 10:18:15 ruslan kernel: ata1: hard resetting link
ноя 14 10:18:15 ruslan kernel: ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
ноя 14 10:18:15 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
ноя 14 10:18:15 ruslan kernel: ata1: EH complete
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x808003ff SErr 0x400000 action 0x6 frozen
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1: SError: { Handshk }
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: cmd 61/c0:00:18:74:7d/08:00:2d:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq dma 1146880 ou
                                           res 40/00:f8:18:6e:7d/00:00:2d:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: cmd 61/20:08:e0:d2:54/00:00:2d:00:00/40 tag 1 ncq dma 16384 out
                                           res 40/00:f8:18:6e:7d/00:00:2d:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: cmd 61/08:10:f0:45:54/00:00:2d:00:00/40 tag 2 ncq dma 4096 out
                                           res 40/00:f8:18:6e:7d/00:00:2d:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: cmd 61/08:18:f8:48:54/00:00:2d:00:00/40 tag 3 ncq dma 4096 out
                                           res 40/00:f8:18:6e:7d/00:00:2d:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: cmd 61/08:20:38:49:54/00:00:2d:00:00/40 tag 4 ncq dma 4096 out
                                           res 40/00:f8:18:6e:7d/00:00:2d:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: cmd 61/18:28:20:6c:54/00:00:2d:00:00/40 tag 5 ncq dma 12288 out
                                           res 40/00:f8:18:6e:7d/00:00:2d:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: cmd 61/18:30:80:6c:54/00:00:2d:00:00/40 tag 6 ncq dma 12288 out
                                           res 40/00:f8:18:6e:7d/00:00:2d:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: cmd 61/18:38:00:6e:54/00:00:2d:00:00/40 tag 7 ncq dma 12288 out
                                           res 40/00:f8:18:6e:7d/00:00:2d:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: cmd 61/18:40:48:6e:54/00:00:2d:00:00/40 tag 8 ncq dma 12288 out
                                           res 40/00:f8:18:6e:7d/00:00:2d:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: cmd 61/18:48:78:6f:54/00:00:2d:00:00/40 tag 9 ncq dma 12288 out
                                           res 40/00:f8:18:6e:7d/00:00:2d:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: cmd 61/00:b8:18:64:7d/0a:00:2d:00:00/40 tag 23 ncq dma 1310720 ou
                                           res 40/00:f8:18:6e:7d/00:00:2d:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: cmd 61/00:f8:18:6e:7d/06:00:2d:00:00/40 tag 31 ncq dma 786432 out
                                           res 40/00:f8:18:6e:7d/00:00:2d:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1: hard resetting link
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
ноя 14 10:18:25 ruslan kernel: ata1: EH complete
```

[image: system_death]

Comment: оказывается уже есть такой вопрос: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1110624/hard-drive-error-ext4-fs-error-failed-to-write-entry-ignoring-read-only-fi, но ответа там нету

Comment: Если файловая система перешла в RO, то скорее всего по диску прошла не восстановимая ошибка. посмотрите системный логи (/var/log/....) там может быть интересная информация. Так же попробуйте поставить пакет smartmontools и посмотреть состояние диска с помощью startctl -A /dev/sda

Comment: Диск вам надо поменять, присоединяюсь к @Mike

Comment: но smart для начала все таки стоит глянуть, у меня как то диск давал сбои из за пыли на контроллере (в смарте при этом видно что поверхность нормальная, а идут ошибки DMA)

Comment: ссдшки умирают внезапно. а ещё чуток остынет и опять работает как новая

Comment: @eri, у меня только hdd

Comment: @dasauser запустите тест на скорость записи. Если отвалится при тесте или будут провалы до 10,20,50 то лучше его сменить

Comment: @eri, какой посоветуете?

Comment: @dasauser проверь сначала этот, может не в нем дело.

Comment: @dasauser а посоветую ссд на nvme в писиай. Интел или самсунг. Из саташных интел можно. Из шпиндилей wd black были норм

Comment: Диск вам надо поменять, присоединяюсь

Comment: @eri, тест какой, а не диск.

Comment: @dasauser приложение "диски", кажется оно вовсех убунтах предустановенно